# Jenkins and SCP

Tags: jenkins, scp

I have set up a jenkins build and everything is working fine except the very last step.

The whole build creates a directory called: `build`

This directory contains a `web-inf` and all the files in it I would like to publish via SCP to a different location, so that all the content of the `build/web-inf` folder will become the content of the target folder.

The settings for jenkins scp plugin are (it is a post-build step):

```
source: build/web-inf/**
destination: public_html/
```

that results in:

```
public_html/build/web-inf/...
```

but should be:

```
public_html/...
```

(the `keep hierarchy` box is ticked)

how can I make that happen??

**EDIT**

I could solve the problem without any additional script. The solution is so simple that my question turned out to be stupid.

All I did was telling ant to copy all the webfiles to `./public_html` instead of `./build/web-inf/` what made the jenkins scp copy all files from `public_html` to `public_html` exactly as it was intended to.

Comment: Feel free to provide an answer to your question with the solution

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to SCP files generated during the build, and the plugin doesn't seem to be working (I couldn't see anything wrong in your configuration) you can use an "Execute shell" build step and type the scp command something like (try it in a shell first in your job's build directory to get the syntax right):

```
scp -r build/web-inf/* user@host:/destination-directory
```